# Resize function by adding 100 pixels on top of what is there now?

Tags: jquery

I recently learned that I could do this: height()+100);

So I when I tried to do:

```
$('.modal1').colorbox.resize({height()+100});
```

I was confused why that did not work. What I want to do is (if possible, without variables) just add extra 100 pixels to the height, is this possible? Thanks :)

Comment: That is syntactically invalid JavaScript. See for yourself: http://jslint.com

Comment: That's an awesome tool Matt. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uh, you're misunderstanding the API. `height` is a method attached to a jQuery object. You'll have to do something like this:

```
// there may be more than one, seeing as this is a class, not an ID selector
$('.modal1').each(function () {
    $(this).colorbox.resize($(this).height() + 100);

    // or this if you are just using jQuery to resize
    // $(this).height($(this).height() + 100);
});
```

Looking at your code, color-box probably has a special handler for 'resize'. For each match, we'll adjust the size using colorbox's resize. If colorbox doesn't have a special resize method, use jQuery's instead. We'll still use the height from jQuery (or we could use colorbox's handler for this if it has one).

Comment: I just looked up the API for resize, and apparently it takes a function, not a int val. It's a handler, not a setter. I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: Well, I use jquery 'case' function for button presses. And all other buttons work, except that that when I add this exact code to this case function, no code under the one I pasted is then executed.

Comment: @pufAmur - I just updated my post. What is 'colorbox' anyway?

Comment: Thanks, I will try it out :) In the meanwhile, I posted a picture of my code: http://i.imgur.com/CIbZ3.png Colorbox id a modal plugin :)

Comment: Hmm no luck: What if we just do a variable which equals the height of .container + 100pixels and then just use that variable in the colorbox resize function?

Comment: Edit: Works now! var elems = $(".container").height()+100; THANK YOU tjameson :)))) for your help!

Comment: @pufAmur - I adjusted my answer based on the code snipped you posted. I don't know what colorbox is, so this is the best I can do.

Comment: You did more than enough tjameson, without your help I would probably still be scratching my head. I really appreciate the time you took to write all that code though, I really really appreciate it !:))